# deleted methods are working java eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat7

I have a problem and it's not at first! 
I have deleted a method but when I run a program it work but eclipse send me a message from methods that was deleted. I have ran in debug mode and without this methods eclipse send me an error!

I have restarted tomcat, eclipse, computer and i had cleaned cache.

Comment: I can bet you that you dint compile it properly, just do project->clean

Comment: It has surfaced: the Zombie Method! ;-) Clean the build.

Comment: hahah this Zombie Method omg:) Thank u) project->clean->work!

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse has a very good memory.  If you want it to forget you said something, you have to convince it that it was never there.  By cleaning your build, you're essentially saying, "These are not the methods you are looking for, move along"